# Can a laminar family of sets be ordered by a Noetherian relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, noetherian

Every pair in a laminar family of sets is either disjoint or related by containment.
Can the pairs which are related by containment be ordered by a Noetherian relation?

Comment: Assuming the axiom of choice, any family of sets can be ordered by a Noetherian relation, but that relation may have nothing to do with $\subseteq$.

Comment: I see. So, in this case $\subseteq$ is a specific case of a Noetherian relation?

Comment: The subset relation on a laminar family need not be Noetherian. Let $A_n=\{2k:0\le k\le n\}$ and $B_n=\{2k+1:0\le k\le n\}$; then $\{A_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a laminar family, but neither $\{A_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ nor $\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is Noetherian with respect to $\subseteq$.